# flush_rewrite_rules() not working with update_option_{$option}

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks, mod-rewrite

Will someone please explain to me why flushing doesn't work in my case. I added a custom settings page with a default value, but it doesn't work when I hit save changes.
I use the `admin_init` hook to register settings like this.

```
register_setting(
                'my_general', 
                'my_general_settings', 
                array(
                    'default'   => 'hello',
                ) 
            );
```

I added sections and fields, and those work. Now I am having a problem with this. If I update or save the settings, the `update_option_my_general_settings` doesn't work. It isn't flushing the rules.
Here is the function code I used inside this hook.

```
if ( $old_value === 'hello' || $value === 'hello' ) {
                // Flush rules
                flush_rewrite_rules();
            }
```

Remember I am supplying these arguments to the function `$old_value, $value, $option`

The filter `mod_rewrite_rules` adds the data to .htaccess after I manually refresh the permalinks inside settings. But the `flush_rewrite_rules()` doesn't seem to be refreshing the permalinks automatically.

**What I want is that when the user updates the settings, the `flush_rewrite_rules` should be populated.**

**More Info**

I basically want to add headers like HSTS, XSS through the WordPress filter `mod_rewrite_rules.` I know I can add these headers by using the WordPress filter '`wp_headers,` but the filter doesn't work in some cases. So I created a settings page. Inside which I created sections and fields. Whenever the user saves the settings I registered with `register_setting(),` the `mod_rewrite_rules` filter is called to add necessary data to the `.htaccess` file. As we will add these headers programmatically, we need to flush the rewrite rules. So, what I did, I found this hook '`update_option{$option}`'. The callback function of this hook stores the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function. Whenever the user sets the value `hello,` the flushing should occur so the data inside the filter will be added to the .htaccess file. I can't post the code because if I do so, the question will be more code than a question. So I tried to keep the question short and to the point.

Here is the code I think would matter. I skipped the settings fields and sections HTML.

```
<?php 
add_action('admin_menu',  'add_settings_page' );
add_action('admin_init', 'register_settings_sections_and_fields' );
add_action( 'update_option_hello_general_settings',  'hello_flush_rewrite_rules' , 10, 3 );

function add_settings_page()
{
    add_options_page('Hello Settings', 'Hello', 'manage_options', 'hello',  'hello_settings_markup'  );
}

function register_settings_sections_and_fields()
{
    register_setting(
        'hello_general', 
        'hello_general_settings', 
        array(
            'default'   => 'filter',
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_section( 'hello_general_section', '', null, 'hello_general' );
    add_settings_field( 'hello_general_settings_method', 'Select Method', 'hello_general_settings_method_callback', 'hello_general', 'hello_general_section' );
}

function hello_settings_markup()
{
?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            settings_fields( 'hello_general' );
            do_settings_sections( 'hello_general' );
            submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
<?php
}

function hello_flush_rewrite_rules( $old_value, $value, $option )
{
    if ( $old_value === 'hello' || $value === 'hello' ) {
        // Flush rules
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
```

**Note: The data gets added to .htaccess after I manually update the permalinks through the dashboard.**

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: There isn't enough information about what you're doing to answer this. We need to know what it is that you're doing in code that requires you to flush the rules, as it has a huge impact on wether it works or not. I know you'd prefer to keep things generic to hide what you're doing but it's unavoidable. We need to know which options you're updating, what it does, what changes you made, the hooks and the functions needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I will update the question with more information. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

flush_rewrite_rules() should be called *very* early within the Wordpress initialization. The reason is that the entpoints cannot be changed afterwards.

A solution could look like this:

```
function updateMySlugOption($old_value, $value, $option) {
    if( $old_value != $value ) {
        set_transient('update_slugs', 1);
    }
}
add_action( 'update_option_mySlug', 'updateMySlugOption', 10, 3);

function update_slugs() {
    if( get_transient('update_slugs') ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        delete_transient('update_slugs');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'update_slugs');
```